# Importing Multiple DB to one MU database

Tags: multisite, database, bulk-import

I have three databases associated with three different WP sites. I set up one MU site, with one database. How should I import each of the three databases?

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is read the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen and http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#WordPress and work with WXR files rather than trying to export directly from the database.

You also have the option on **Import** to grab images. Or you can merge the contents of the three wp-content/uploads/ directories, but be aware that it's possible some images may have the same name and get overwritten.

Comment: Be aware that the regular WXR file will miss authors without posts.

Comment: @toscho: is there a workaround for that? A quick search doesn't reveal one.

Comment: A custom exporter or a hidden custom post type with `'can_export'` and one ghost post per user. Not exactly elegant solutions.